# How to persist in EhCache open source?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I'm using EhCache to cache serialized objects of a REST API response. Looks like there is no way to persist data for restart or unexpected crash in latest release version (2.10.x) of EhCache open source. I can think of looping through the list of elements in cache using cache.getKeys(), serialize the Element objects and then later deserialize the Element objects and add them into cache when the application comes up. Is there any other cleaner way ?

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache 2.10.x offers a [disk tier](https://ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-tiers_configuring_storage_tiers.html%23) that can be restartable.

However, the open source implementation is not resilient to failures and so most crash situation that do not allow the `CacheManager` and `Cache`s to be closed properly will cause the data to be lost at restart.

The commercial Enterprise version offers a much more [robust disk store](http://terracotta.org/generated/4.3.0/html/bmg-all/#page/BigMemory_Go_Documentation_Set%2Fto-fast_configuring_fast_restart.html%23wwconnect_header).